# manual inject into the constructor got error signature

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to implement a logger to sqlite.

ilogger.ts

```
export interface ILogger {
    write (log: Log): any;
}
```

ilogger.service.ts

```
export interface ILoggerService {
    info(log: Log): any;
    error(log: Log): any;
}
```

irepository.ts

```
export interface IRepository<T> {
    find(key: number): any;
    insert(data: T): any;
    remove(key: number): any;
    fetch(count: number, skip: number): any;
}
```

sqlite.logger.impl.ts

```
export class SqliteLoggerImpl implements ILogger {

    sqliteRepo: IRepository<Log>;

    SqliteLoggerImpl(sqliteRepo: IRepository<Log>) {
        this.sqliteRepo = sqliteRepo;
    }

    write(log: Log): any {
        return this.sqliteRepo.insert(log);
    }
}
```

logger.service.impl.ts

```
export class LoggerServiceImpl implements ILoggerService {
    logger: ILogger;

    LoggerServiceImpl(logger: ILogger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    info(log: Log): any {
        log.severity = 0;
        return this.logger.write(log);
    }

    error(log: Log): any {
        log.severity = 1;
        return this.logger.write(log);
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
    logs: Array<Log>;
    loggerService: ILoggerService;

    constructor() {
        let repo: IRepository<Log> = new SqliteRepositoryImpl();

        // [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
        let logger: ILogger = new SqliteLoggerImpl(repo);
        this.loggerService = new LoggerServiceImpl(logger);
    }
}
```

I don't understand at these two lines:

```
let logger: ILogger = new SqliteLoggerImpl(repo);
this.loggerService = new LoggerServiceImpl(logger);
```

SqliteLoggerImpl constructor needs an IRepository, and I already give it.
LoggerServiceImpl constructor needs an ILogger, and I already give it.

Why still I see this, "[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" ?

Comment: new SqliteRepositoryImpl(); where is this class?

Comment: You have to declare contructor like `constructor(sqliteRepo: IRepository<Log>)` instead of `SqliteLoggerImpl(sqliteRepo: IRepository<Log>) {` everywhere.

Comment: @yurzui, you caught it, thank you so much.
That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript isn't like other languages where the constructor is the name of the class. You need to use the keyword `constructor`. What you have in all your implementations is just a method in the class that is the same name of the class. This method is *not* what is called when using `new`. It is the `constructor`. And every class has a default no-arg constructor when we don't define one. So when you try to do `new Something(someArg)`, this will fail, as the default no-arg constructor doesn't take arguments. So just change all your "supposed constructors" to `constructor`s

Comment: Thank peeskillet, this is the correct answer :-D
I wish i could up vote this answer.